# How to add new row from another table with union?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I should add a new row from table products which owner is sales(sh) to product_name_us and prod_desc to product_desc_us using an union .

```
SELECT temp.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN 
COALESCE(TO_CHAR(pd.TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
                      END AS PRODUCT_NAME_US,
                      CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'US' THEN 
CONCAT(SUBSTR(pd.TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...')
                      END AS PRODUCT_DESC_US,
                      CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' AND pd.translated_name
 IS NULL THEN COALESCE(TO_CHAR(pd.TRANSLATED_NAME), ' ')
                      END AS PRODUCT_NAME_RU,
                      CASE WHEN pd.LANGUAGE_ID = 'RU' AND 
pd.translated_description IS NULL THEN 
CONCAT(SUBSTR(pd.TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...')
                      END AS PRODUCT_DESC_RU,
                      CASE 
                           WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) = 

'00'  THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD) || ' years'



                      END AS "Warranty", inv.QUANTITY_ON_HAND AS IN_STOCK 

FROM PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS pd JOIN PRODUCT_INFORMATION pin

ON pd.PRODUCT_ID = pin.PRODUCT_ID

JOIN INVENTORIES inv

ON inv.PRODUCT_ID = pin.PRODUCT_ID) temp




WHERE temp.PRODUCT_NAME_US LIKE '%Monitor%' 

AND temp.IN_STOCK < 100

union all (select PROD_NAME,PROD_DESC from sh.products);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want to add a row as a footer to your first select.
 Using union is only available if your 2 selects having same amount of columns

```html
select 'field1' as a, 'field2' as b, 'field3' as c from dual
union all
select '1', '2', null from dual;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs8qM.png)

But if you want to use in your second query column from your first one to match it is impossible because its outside the select statement

Comment: I tried this one 
union all (select sh.products.prod_name,sh.products.prod_desc,null,null,to_char('1 year'),to_number(100),null from sh.products)